# How to have a symbol appear in a radio button before it is selected

Tags: css

I am using an adapted version of some nice CSS radio buttons that I found [here](https://codepen.io/msisto/pen/lCofE), but I need them to have symbols in them, as each one will represent a specific user action.  Specifically, I am using a plus symbol and an arrow symbol.  I am able to change the "X" symbol in the custom radio buttons to a plus symbol and an arrow symbol, but I cannot figure out how to have them still appear before the radio button itself is selected.  Right now, you can only see it after it is selected.  I have tried moving the `content: '\25B2'` property to every other selector in the CSS, but it never seems to appear, I still have to select the radio button before it becomes visible. I really need these symbols to be visible at all times so they user knows which one to select.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzw7kexv/)

Comment: Look for all related styles declared with the `:checked` *pseudo-class* and apply those styles to the unchecked or natural state, e.g: `.pyramid-add-radio:checked::after` to `.pyramid-add-radio::after`. On a side note, you may want to tread carefully when using *pseudo-elements*, like `:before` and `after`, on self-closing/void or replaced elements, like `input` elements, in production code; since the specification doesn't seem to be clear on whether this will consistently and reliably apply as expected in all browsers all of the time.

Comment: Generally these *pseudo-classes* only apply to *containing elements*; elements that may or can contain content. Technically, `input` fields don't *contain content* but rather *contain values*.

Answer (score -2):

```
you need to set checked pass **checked** attribute in input type radio like
```

below.
    [here is code](http://jsfiddle.net/RbH9N/78/)